# PHP to ignore a string block from str_replace

Tags: php, regex

I am working to clean up CSS output with str_replace, but need to ignore certain block of strings with a defined start and end.

Ignore anything that starts with:

```
@media blah(this can be any value) {
```

content to ignore:

```
  .class {
    property: value;
  }
```

and ends with:

```
}/*ends*/
```

And do str_replace outside that block instead:

```
.otherclass {property:value;}
```

PHP:

```
$output = str_replace("{", "{\n", $output);
$output = str_replace("}", "}\n", $output);
```

The reason is that @media block need proper indentation which is already correctly formatted, and  should not be touched by str_replace which simple return readable lines:

```
 .otherclass {
  property:value;
  }
```

How would you say it in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: imo it's a weird approach to format a file. Look into regex, more flexibility there... Or read in entire file into array and scan thorough the array. If you encounter opening tag `{` indent, if you find `@media` skip etc... Also, see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376958/linux-automated-code-formatting-php-javascript-html-css-mysql

Comment: Its dynamic aggregation and extraction of CSS, thats why they have different format of CSS code blocks, so IDE is no go here. A custom input based on setting definition, which mostly format that blocks that want to ignore, and a few copie of external CSS files and appended into a single file as a compressed unreadable version put along with that custom input. Now I need to process those aggregated/compressed version into more readable CSS code block while ignoring some @media block. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = 
"@media blah(this can be any value) {
.class {
    property: value;
  }
}/*ends*/

.otherclass {property:value;}

.otherclass {property:value;}

@media blah(this can be any value) {
.class {
    property: value;
  }
}/*ends*/

.otherclass {property:value;}

.otherclass {property:value;}";

$arr = explode("\r", $string);

$ignore_block = false;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
    if (strstr($arr[$i], '@media'))
        $ignore_block = true;
    elseif (strstr($arr[$i-1], '/*ends*/'))
        $ignore_block = false;

    if ($ignore_block == false)
    {
        $arr[$i] = str_replace("{", "{\n\t", $arr[$i]);
        $arr[$i] = str_replace("}", "\n}\n", $arr[$i]);
    }
}
file_put_contents("test.txt", implode("\n", $arr));
```

Regex won't work since lookbehind doesn't allow variable length.  Try and loop through the file.

Comment: Thanks. Almost works, except for Notice: Undefined offset: -1

Comment: Right, you should check the `$i-1` for the initial iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I also think that regular expressions are the way to go as they give you much more flexibility.

I guess the naive solution is to first fetch all those occurrences from the output source, then using str_replace on the remaining code and then putting it back. Might also try going through the code line after line and only running str_replace

Again, your best chance is with Regular Expressions. What you're looking for seems to be preg_replace, telling it not to match anything followed before by @media

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can't count, so they're not *generally* appropriate for parsing (which is what you're doing). Ie, unless you can restrict the input format more than the full set of valid CSS, you may find some cases don't work as expected.

You could also try fully parsing the CSS and walk the resultant CSS tree using rules to specify how you output the data. There's apparently a CSS parser library here:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1289-PHP-CSS-parser-class.html

Comment: PCRE (used by PHP's `preg_*` functions) can "count" (I'm assuming here you mean recurse, balancing pairs like braces `{` and `}`; **all** regex can *count*: `.{3,14}`). Sure, recursion isn't "regular" and PCRE isn't either, but it's certainly a valid tool for token matching.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant usefully recursive counting. Repetition counting is of course supported widely (theres +, *, ?, {num}, and {min,max}). But I'm not sure balanced matching helps here.